# Twilio : Dial with two Audio, each for From and To numbers : PHP

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I have to use twilio to use two audio file, one for the person who is calling, and second audio is for the person who is being called.

Its like terms and condition,

`terms_conditions_v1.mp3` for `person1`

`terms_conditions_v2.mp3` for `person2`

person1 will call on twilio number which will be forwarded to person2.

both audio files should end in same time, say 20 seconds.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you got any code you can show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating two TwiML conference file. Keep the friendly name of conferences same and so they will connect. Make both calls simultaneously. Here is what I did in each xml file,

```
<Response>
<Play>mp3</Play>
<Dial>
<Conference>Frindly_name</Conference>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

as both my audio files have same length, there is very little waiting time.